# How to use nexusupload to upload artifact if using SAP piperpipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, nexus3, sap-project-piper

We are using SAP piperpipeline. At the root level, application source code folder and mta.yaml file is present.

The pom.xml file is available under application folder.

I am trying to upload the .jar file generated in "Build" stage to nexus.
The nexus upload should execute in "promote" stage of SAP piperpipeline.

in the config.yaml file (present at the root level), the below configurations have been added for nexus upload:

```
steps:
  mtaBuild:
    dockerImage: '<docker_image_name>'
  nexusUpload:
    url: '<nexus_url>'
    format: 'maven'
    groupId: '<group_id>'
    mavenRepository: '<maven_repository>'
    nexusCredentialsId: 'nexus_id'
    version: 'nexus3'   
    verbose: true
```

After nexusupload, in reponse I am getting 204 code.

How can I upload the jar generated in build stage to nexus in promote stage?

Answer (score 0):

a 204 response implies your upload was successful. Refer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/components-api

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).